# javax.naming.exception:JNDI look up failed Error communicating with router

Tags: jndi, solace

I am getting below exception on connecting to solace for the first time

javax.naming.exception:JNDI lookup failed Error communicating with router. Appreciate your help.
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
// use the Solace JNDI initial context factory
env.put(InitialContext.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory");

```
    // assign Solace message router connection parameters
    env.put(InitialContext.PROVIDER_URL, host);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + '@' + vpnName); // Formatted as user@message-vpn
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    // Create the initial context that will be used to lookup the JMS Administered Objects.
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
    // Lookup the connection factory
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_NAME);

    // Create connection to the Solace router
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

    // Create a non-transacted, client ACK session.
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, SupportedProperty.SOL_CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    System.out.printf("Connected to the Solace Message VPN '%s' with client username '%s'.%n", vpnName,
            username);

    // Lookup the queue.
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup(QUEUE_JNDI_NAME);

    // From the session, create a consumer for the destination.
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the Solace PubSub+ broker was not reachable by your application. Please ensure that the plain-text SMF service is up on the broker side and that the application host can communicate with the broker over port 55555.